# BigCommerce and NodeJS Apps - Auth, Load, Uninstall Process

Tags: node.js, bigcommerce

I haven't had a lot of experience in using node and BigCommerce together and this is really my first time trying. I have a NodeJS deployed on Amazon's AWS EB, at the moment when I try to install my draft App on BigCommerce, it gets stuck in the installation and the progress indicator stays indefinitely.

I'm using a npm package node-bigcommerce that is mentioned in BigCommerce's docs:
https://github.com/getconversio/node-bigcommerce/

At the moment my config looks like:

```
const bigCommerce = new BigCommerce({
    logLevel: "info",
    clientId: "my id",
    secret: "my secret",
    callback: "hostname",
    responseType: "json",
    apiVersion: "v3" // Default is v2
});
```

and the code I'm using for auth, load, uninstall:

```
router.get("/auth", (req, res, next) => {
    bigCommerce
        .authorize(req.query)
        .then(data => res.render("auth", { title: "Authorized!", data: data }))
        .catch(next);
});

router.get("/load", (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const data = bigCommerce.verify(req.query["signed_payload"]);
        res.render("load", { title: "Welcome!", data: data });
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
});

router.get("/uninstall", (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const data = bigCommerce.verify(req.query["signed_payload"]);
        res.render("uninstall", { title: "Uninstalled!", data: data });
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
});
```

I've also tried using regular app.get('/', cb) as well, nothing.
Also I've seen the following get returned in data by auth:

```
{ title: "Authorized!", data: "<html><body>You are being <a href="https://login.bigcommerce.com/login">redirected</a>.</body></html>" }
```

I'm not quite sure how to approach this, and there isn't too much documentation on working with node and BC together. How might I proceed?

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. Was a couple of things, I completely forgot about setting up HTTPS on the node server, but after that was setup, the loading progress overlay finally went away. The other missing link was that the package I'm using https://github.com/getconversio/node-bigcommerce , inside the request headers, they're using applications/json, but this should be "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" after those couple changes everything worked.